# How to seperate normal exit or error of execution of bash script

Tags: java, bash

I will execute a bash script from Java and my question is how to distinguish normal exit from failed one.

I know theorically it returns 0 for normal exit and non zero for others. But what if the script call **"exit 1"** or **"exit 255"**? If "exit 127" it will return 127 but there is no "command not found" error.

The only way I find is to ready the errOutputFile but it looks like stupid ...

PS: I used Process.waitfor() to get the exit code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this part: "If "exit 127" it will return 127 but there is no "command not found" error."

Comment: @Drux I mean for bash script, if it execute an inexistent command, il will return error code of 127 which indicates "command not found". for example, " qjzoiegj ". However I can also execute " exit 127 " to get a return value of 127. that's why i say I cant distinguish successful execution from failed one.

Comment: I see. In this case I think you really have to look at the output (not only the exit code) to make the exact distinction.

Comment: @java_learner _"I can also execute `exit 127` to get a return value of 127"_ You don't use `exit` to return a **value**. You use it to return an **exit code**. By convention, `0` means OK. Anything else means there was an error. If your script needs to "return some value", it _should_ write it to its standard output and terminate with a status code of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Process.waitFor() [ref. here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) will return the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination. So if you use exit you get the exit code specified.

*The command not found error you are getting is self-explanatory.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "/tmp/test.sh" };
        BufferedReader bri = null, bre = null;
        int exitC = 0;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            exitC = p.waitFor();
            bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);               
            }
            while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            bri.close();
            bre.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("Exit Code: "+ exitC);
    }
```

Bash test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello World
exit 127
```

console

```
Hello World
Exit Code: 127
```